# MacPort and LaunchAgent without sudo

Tags: sudo, macports

I'm running Snow Leopard and am trying to install Wine.

To keep things simple, I'm trying to install Wine using MacPorts.

My MacPorts is local to ~/opt/local/.

However, one of the required packages for Wine is dbus.  During activation, dbus wants to write to /Library/LaunchAgents/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist.  Of course, this is protected (as it should be).

So how do I modify the MacPort install to write the plist elsewhere and modify the startup commands appropriately so that this alternate location is used instead?

Part of this is lack of understanding of LaunchAgent.  Are these daemons that start on user login or on system startup?

Comment: Good question with respect to MacPorts. Although, to keep things simple, it may be easier to use [WineBottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/).

Comment: /Library/LaunchAgents start on system startup, ~/Library/LaunchAgents are per-user and start on user login (note the ~ for the per-user ones).